# Debugging F# data provider problems

Tags: debugging, f#, nullreferenceexception, freebase, f#-data

I'm trying to extract a place from the freebase provider in F# and I finally got it working. I want to fill a custom class "Place" ( from a C#) library.Everything was going fine until I had an error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This error happens on this line:

```
 tempAddress.Address <- firstPlace.``Street address``.``Street Address`` |> Seq.head
```

So I wanted to debug it and see what's going wrong. I have everything in Debug mode, the optimize code checkbox, unchecked. I made a clean and rebuild solution. Everything in Debug. I put a breakpoint in that line, and, for my surprise, I cannot see any locals, variables, nothing. Just the breakpoint stoped! This is the code I'm using:

```
 let Extract mid = let dataWithKey = FreebaseDataWithKey.GetDataContext()
                  let place = dataWithKey.Commons.Travel.``Travel destinations``.Where( fun x-> x.MachineId = mid) |> Seq.toList                           
                  let result = new Place()   
                  let firstPlace = place.Head                                    

                  result.Name <- firstPlace.Name

                  let tempAddress = new FBAddress()
                  tempAddress.Address <- firstPlace.``Street address``.``Street Address`` |> Seq.head

                  result
```

When debuggin I only see this on the Locals window

```
        mid Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'mid' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away. string
```

But again, I have everything in debug. For instance, I can debug normal C# code, this only happens in the F# project.

Is there any way to make VS2013 show me the locals? or show my anything on watch happening there? Thanks!

**EDIT** I made a little test with another peace of code, one who checks if a word is palindrome, and I was able to debug, step in to the code, and watch locals and variables. Just when I downloaded the nuget package of FSharp.Data and started coding it stoped debuging correctly. I have seen that the locals disappear when this line is called:

```
let place = dataWithKey.Commons.Travel.``Travel destinations``.Where( fun x-> x.MachineId = mid) |> Seq.toList
```

Before it I was able to see the "mid" variable content

Comment: I can't reproduce. What's the value of mid?

Comment: Try with this mid "/m/04jpl" it's the id of London.

Answer (score 1):

With erased type providers the code you see is very different from what's being actually done at runtime, so sometimes the debugger has some trouble. Freebase is even worse because there's a lot of IQueryable transformations going on. Have you tried checking the "Enable source server support" in the VS options, under the Debugger section, and trying to step into the FSharp.Data source code?

Comment: Hi Gustavo, I enabled the source server support, rebuilt the project, but couldn't step into FSharp.Data source code.